# Unknown runtime error number: -2146827687

Tags: javascript, gwt, gxt

I have an error in my GXT code on Internet Explorer (both Development Mode and not) when i try to attach a label to a panel.
The error is "Unknown runtime error number: -2146827687" but this error in a GWT module is throws always, in other gwt modules with a label attached to the panel the error there isn't.

The layout of panel is a GridFormLayout developed by me. The error is thrown when the renderComponentInCell is called (the method is called on doLayout) and the component is not rendered (else condition).

```
private void renderComponentInCell(Component component, Element cell) {   
    if (component.isRendered()) {
      cell.appendChild(component.getElement());
    } else {
      component.render(cell);
    }
  }
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a jsni or javascript exception somewhere in the layout method of your component. I see these from time to time and I always fine that Firefox throws them also, they just get eaten someplace.

I bet if you compile your module using pretty, and then debug through the layout using Firebug or Venkman, you will find a null pointer or such in the JS code.

Answer (score 1):

That's probably -1 being misformatted during output.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what do you mean